# Proof of Motzkin numbers recurrence

Tags: combinatorics

I know the Motzkin numbers are given as $$M_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n \choose 2k}C_k,$$ where $$C_k=\frac{1}{1+k}{2k\choose k}.$$
The recurrence relation is given as $M_n=M_{n-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}M_kM_{n-2-k}$. Is there a direct way to prove this recurrence using either Pascal's identity or summation by parts?

Comment: The [combinatorial interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number) in terms of paths makes the recurrence relation pretty trivial.

Comment: We can simplify a bit: $\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{2k}\binom{2k}{k} = \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{k} = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}\binom{n-k}{k}$. The first transformation uses $\binom{r}{m}\binom{m}{k} = \binom{r}{k}\binom{r-k}{m-k}$. The second uses $\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$

Comment: We can give a direct combinatorial proof. Motzkin numbers count Motzkin paths. To construct a Motzkin path of length $n$, do the following. (1) Choose the $2k$ positions for the up and down steps in $\binom{n}{2k}$ ways. The subsequence of those steps is a Dyck path of semilength $k$, so the number of such sequences is $C_k$. Then (2) Insert level steps in the remaining positions.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach starts from

$$M_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n\choose 2k} C_k.$$

This is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n\choose n-2k} C_k
\\ =  \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} C_k [z^{n-2k}] (1+z)^n C_k
= [z^n] (1+z)^n  \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} C_k z^{2k}.$$

Now  when  $2k\gt n$  there  is  no  contribution to  the  coefficient
extractor and hence we may extend the sum to infinity:

$$[z^n] (1+z)^n  \sum_{k\ge 0} C_k z^{2k}.$$

Using the generating function of the Catalan numbers this becomes

$$[z^n] (1+z)^n  \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z^2}}{2z^2}$$

which is

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
(1+z)^n  \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z^2}}{2z^2}.$$

With $z/(1+z) = w$ we have $z = w/(1-w)$ and $dz = 1/(1-w)^2 \; dw$
and obtain

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{1}{w^n} \frac{(1-w)^3}{2w^3} (1-\sqrt{1-4w^2/(1-w)^2})
\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1-w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{2w^2}.$$

This shows that

$$M_n = [w^n] \frac{1-w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{2w^2},$$

which is also the LHS of the recurrence. We get for the RHS

$$[w^{n-1}] \frac{1-w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{2w^2}
+ [w^{n-2}] \frac{(1-w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2})^2}{4w^4}
\\ = [w^{n}] \frac{2w-2w^2-2w\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{4w^2}
+ [w^{n}] \frac{(1-w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2})^2}{4w^2}.$$

The numerator is

$$2w-2w^2-2w\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2} + 2 - 4w - 2w^2
- 2(1-w)\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}
\\ = 2 - 2w - 4w^2 - 2 \sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}.$$

We therefore conclude that the RHS is

$$[w^n] \left(-1 + \frac{1-w-\sqrt{1-2w-3w^2}}{2w^2}\right),$$

which is the same as the LHS when $n\ge 2,$ as claimed.